# Asyncio decode utf-8 with StreamReader

Tags: python, asynchronous, encoding, utf-8, python-asyncio

I am getting used to asyncio and find the task handling quite nice, but it can be difficult to mix async libraries with traditional io libraries.  The problem I am currently facing is how to properly decode an async StreamReader.

The simplest solution is to `read()` chunks of byte strings, and then decode each chunk - see code below. (In my program, I wouldn't print each chunk, but decode it into a string and send it into another method for processing):

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp

async def get_data(port):
    url = 'http://localhost:{}/'.format(port)
    r = await aiohttp.get(url)
    stream = r.content
    while not stream.at_eof():
        data = await stream.read(4)
        print(data.decode('utf-8'))
```

This works fine, until there is a utf-8 character that is split between too chunks. For example if the response is `b'M\xc3\xa4dchen mit Bi\xc3\x9f\n'`, then reading chunks of 3 will work, but chunks of 4 will not (as `\xc3` and `\x9f` are in different chunks and decoding the chunk ending with `\xc3` will raise the following error:

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 3: unexpected end of data`

I looked at proper solutions to this problem, and at least in the blocking world, seems to be either io.TextIOWrapper or codecs.StreamReaderWriter (the differences of which are discussed in [PEP 0400](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0400/)).  However, both of these rely on typical blocking streams.

I spent 30 minutes searching for examples with asyncio and kept finding my decode() solution.  Does anyone know of a better solution or is this a missing feature in python's asyncio?

For reference, here are the results from using the two "standard" decoders with async streams.

Using the codec stream reader:

```
r = yield from aiohttp.get(url)
decoder = codecs.getreader('utf-8')
stream = decoder(r.content)
```

Exception:

```
File "echo_client.py", line 13, in get_data
  data = yield from stream.read(4)
File "/usr/lib/python3.5/codecs.py", line 497, in read
  data = self.bytebuffer + newdata
TypeError: can't concat bytes to generator
```

(it calls read() directly, rather than `yield from` or `await` it)

I also tried wrapping stream with io.TextIOWrapper:

```
stream = TextIOWrapper(r.content)
```

But that leads to the following:

```
File "echo_client.py", line 10, in get_data
  stream = TextIOWrapper(r.content)
AttributeError: 'FlowControlStreamReader' object has no attribute 'readable'
```

P.S. If you want a sample test case for this, please look at [this gist](https://gist.github.com/ethanfrey/75e58db27095936b9e5e).  You can run it with python3.5 to reproduce the error.  If you change the chunk size from 4 to 3 (or 30), it will work correctly.

**EDIT**

The accepted answer fixed this like a charm.  Thanks!  If someone else has this issue, here is a simple wrapper class I made to handle the decoding on a StreamReader:

```
import codecs

class DecodingStreamReader:
    def __init__(self, stream, encoding='utf-8', errors='strict'):
        self.stream = stream
        self.decoder = codecs.getincrementaldecoder(encoding)(errors=errors)

    async def read(self, n=-1):
        data = await self.stream.read(n)
        if isinstance(data, (bytes, bytearray)):
            data = self.decoder.decode(data)
        return data

    def at_eof(self):
        return self.stream.at_eof()
```

Comment: And before someone asks why I don't just load the entire response in memory, consider web sockets or long keep alive feeds (such as couchdb's _changes feed in continuous mode).  I want to parse each incoming data, as it arrives, without waiting (possibly minutes) for the HTTP connection to close.

Comment: It might be related to this bug: https://bugs.python.org/issue31087

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use an [IncrementalDecoder](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.IncrementalDecoder):

```
Utf8Decoder = codecs.getincrementaldecoder('utf-8')
```

With your example:

```
decoder = Utf8Decoder(error='strict')
while not stream.at_eof():
    data = await stream.read(4)
    print(decoder.decode(data), end='')
```

Output:

```
Mädchen mit Biß
```

Comment: Great!  I tried it and it works perfect.  Thanks for the quick answer.