# JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) error

Tags: python, json, django, api, decode

I am facing this error while making request to fetch json from api.

I can get json data using the "/v1/articles' path.

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.xxxx.com.tr")
    headers = {
    'accept': "application/json", 
    'apikey': "cd6b6c96799847698d87dec9f9a731d6"
    }
    filter = "daily"
    conn.request("GET", "/v1/articles", headers=headers)
    reader = codecs.getreader("utf-8")
    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = json.load(reader(res))
    json.dumps(data)
    return data
```

But i am having JSONDecodeError if i set filter. Code:

```
conn = http.client.HTTPSConnection("api.xxxx.com.tr")
    headers = {
    'accept': "application/json", 
    'apikey': "cd6b6c96799847698d87dec9f9a731d6"
    }
    conn.request("GET", "/v1/articles?$filter=Path eq '/daily/'", headers=headers)
    reader = codecs.getreader("utf-8")
    res = conn.getresponse()
    data = json.load(reader(res))
    json.dumps(data)
    return data
```

I tried same filter using Postman with no error and i can get Json data.

Returned Json data from Postman:

```
[
    {
        "Id": "40778196",
        "ContentType": "Article",
        "CreatedDate": "2018-03-20T08:28:05.385Z",
        "Description": "İspanya'da 2016 yılında çalınan lüks otomobil, şasi numarası değiştirilerek Bulgaristan üzerinden getirildiği Türkiye'de bulundu.",
        "Files": [
            {
                "FileUrl": "http://i.xxxx.com/i/xxxx/98/620x0/5ab0c6a9c9de3d18a866eb54.jpg",
                "Metadata": {
                    "Title": "",
                    "Description": ""
                }
            }
        ],
        "ModifiedDate": "2018-03-20T08:32:12.001Z",
        "Path": "/gundem/",
        "StartDate": "2018-03-20T08:32:12.001Z",
        "Tags": [
            "ispanya",
            "Araç",
            "Hırsız",
            "Dolandırıcı"
        ],
        "Title": "İspanya'da çalınan lüks araç Türkiye'de bulundu!",
        "Url": "http://www.xxxx.com.tr/gundem/ispanyada-calinan-luks-arac-turkiyede-bulundu-40778196"
    }
 ]
```

I can not figure out the problem. It would be great if anyone help me about this issue. Thank you.

Comment: it is very hard to solve cause I don't have access to your resource, I can only suggest using a more robust client like **requests** that might solve the issue http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/

Comment: `conn.request("GET", "/v1/articles?$filter=Path eq '/daily/'", headers=headers)` Are you sure the url should have `$`?

Comment: @DeepSpace yes url should have it.

Comment: I really, really doubt that. And it shouldn't have spaces or quotes either. What is the API you are connecting to?

Comment: There are other odd things about this code too. For instance, `json.dumps(data)` on its own does *literally nothing*.

Comment: @DanielRoseman api docs: https://developers.hurriyet.com.tr/docs/versions/1.0/resources/article

If it shouldn't have spaces or quotes how come the postman response me with json data?

Comment: That page shows examples of URLs, and they don't have $ or spaces - those characters are encoded properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally figured out the problem! Using the `requests` library have solved my problem now I can filter the api request.

```
data = requests.get('https://api.xxxxx.com.tr/v1/articles', headers =
headers, params={"$filter":"Path eq '/xxxxxx/'"}).json()
```

I am leaving this answer here for anyone else who can need this solution in the future.
Thanks for all your suggestions.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the following line

```
data = json.load(reader(res))
```

when your response is not a json string, `JSONDecodeError` occurs. so, add an additional logic to see if the response is `None` or a `json` string. First thing, print the `reader(res)` and see what the return is

Comment: I have tried to print reader(res) this is what returned.

<encodings.utf_8.StreamReader object at 0x06D01370>

Comment: can you look into this link, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35036921/asyncio-decode-utf-8-with-streamreader

Comment: oh, can you pickle that output and share it here, may be i can take a look

Comment: i included the traceback into the question. thank you for the effort.

Comment: no, not the traceback. to correct it we need to decode the object that is being returned in the response. so, if you could save the object as pickle file and upload it here, i can try getting the json out of it